Entity Framework Core with Npgsql: Duplicate key value violates unique constraint "PK_Posts"
I'm encountering an issue while trying to save a new PostEntity to my PostgreSQL database using Entity Framework Core with Npgsql. The error message indicates a violation of the unique constraint on the primary key for the Posts table. Here is the detailed error:
fail: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20102]
      Failed executing DbCommand (14ms) [Parameters=[@p0='?' (DbType = Guid), @p1='?', @p2='?' (DbType = DateTime), @p3='?' (DbType = Boolean), @p4='?', @p5='?' (DbType = Object), @p6='?', @p7='?' (DbType = Guid)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      INSERT INTO "Posts" ("Id", "Content", "CreatedAt", "IsArchive", "Location", "Tags", "Title", "UserId")
      VALUES (@p0, @p1, @p2, @p3, @p4, @p5, @p6, @p7);
fail: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update[10000]
      An exception occurred in the database while saving changes for context type 'Facebook.Infrastructure.Common.Persistence.FacebookDbContext'.
      Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException: An error occurred while saving the entity changes. See the inner exception for details.
       ---> Npgsql.PostgresException (0x80004005): 23505: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "PK_Posts"
      
      DETAIL: Detail redacted as it may contain sensitive data. Specify 'Include Error Detail' in the connection string to include this information.

Here is my PostEntity class:
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using Facebook.Domain.User;

namespace Facebook.Domain.Post
{
    public class PostEntity
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string? Title { get; set; }
        public string? Content { get; set; }
        public List<string>? Tags { get; set; }
        public string? Location { get; set; }
        public ICollection<ImagesEntity>? Images { get; set; }
        public bool IsArchive { get; set; }
        
        private DateTime _createdAt;
        public DateTime CreatedAt
        {
            get { return _createdAt; }
            set { _createdAt = DateTime.SpecifyKind(value, DateTimeKind.Utc); }
        }
        
        [ForeignKey("UserEntity")]
        public Guid UserId { get; set; } 
        public UserEntity User { get; set; }
    }
}

And here is my UserEntity class:
using Facebook.Domain.Post;
using Facebook.Domain.Story;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Facebook.Domain.User
{
    public class UserEntity : IdentityUser<Guid>
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        
        private DateTime _birthday;
        public DateTime Birthday
        {
            get { return _birthday; }
            set { _birthday = DateTime.SpecifyKind(value, DateTimeKind.Utc); }
        }
        
        public string? Avatar { get; set; }
        public string Gender { get; set; }
        
        public ICollection<StoryEntity> Stories { get; set; } = new List<StoryEntity>();
        public ICollection<PostEntity> Posts { get; set; } = new List<PostEntity>();
    }
}

What I've tried:
Ensured that the Id for each new PostEntity is unique by using Guid.NewGuid()
Checked the database to confirm that no duplicate Id values exist
What could be causing this duplicate key value violates unique constraint "PK_Posts" error and how can I resolve it? Any guidance on how to debug this issue further would be appreciated.

You didn't post any code that actually inserts into the database. It's quite possible you tried to use the same GUID value for multiple PostEntity objects, or didn't specify one at all.

The error says you can get more information if you add the Include Error Detail keyword in the connection string. This will probably show the actual duplicate PK values.

@PanagiotisKanavos this is my create post method:
public async Task<ErrorOr> CreatePostAsync(PostEntity post)
{
try
{
_context.Posts.Add(post);
await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
return post.Id;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
return Error.Failure(ex.Message);
}
}

@Doberman, update your question with real code. Do not post it in comments.

That snippet doesn't seem to set post.Id anywhere so it's Guid.Empty.  There's no model configuration that shows Id is generated by the database. Please add the action code and the model configuration code in the question itself.

If you want to set the ID client-side, add [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)] above the Id property in your entity. By default convention EF expects a property named "Id" or "PostId" to be an identity column (configured to be populated by the DB) so it will ignore an value even if you set one on an Added entity.
